# Why doesn't Google OpenID provider work with PHP-OpenId on my server?

Tags: php, openid

I'm using [PHP-OpenId](http://www.openidenabled.com/php-openid/) 2.1.3 which I've unzipped on my server [here](http://endesha.com/openid/php-openid-2.1.3/examples/consumer) (this is the consumer example that comes with PHP-OpenId). When I enter the Google OpenId url (https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id) and submit I get a blank screen.

When I try the exact same example code on the PHP-OpenId website [here](http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/trunk/examples/consumer/) with the same URL it works fine.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. The only thing I can think of is that somehow Google does not want to work with my server.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

If it breaks for Google and Yahoo but works for certain other providers, it's likely the setup for making HTTPS requests is borked on your PHP server.  Check to make sure you have the ca-certificates package installed.

Comment: I've got ca-certificates installed on server, but I still experience problems with curl and Google/Yahoo. Do you need to enable them somehow in my PHP, install some extension maybe?

Answer (score 0):

ketrun is right, I had a similar problem. After I installed the ca-certificates package, everything was fine, but when there is a problem with https requests, PHP Openid returns an error (invalid openid), not a blank screen.

Be sure to check the detect.php file from the examples dir and discover.php to check your OpenID URLs.