# Why would "/id" as a HTTP GET parameter would be a security breach?

Tags: apache, hosting, web-hosting, security

While trying to debug my openid implementation with Google, which kept returning Apache 406 errors, I in the end discovered that my hosting company does not allow to pass a string containing "/id" as a GET parameter (something like "example.php?anyattribute=%2Fid" once URL encoded).

That's rather annoying as Google openid endpoint includes this death word "/id" (https://google.com/accounts/o8/id) so my app is returning 406 errors every time I log in with Google because of this. I contacted my hosting company who told me this has been deactivated for security purposes.

I could use POST instead, for sure. But has anyone got an idea why this could cause security problems ???

Comment: Why not contact your hosting company again and request more details regarding the issue?

Comment: Have you asked the hosting company to explain *why* they think this is a problem? If they can't explain it to you, then they don't know why they're doing it, which suggests they probably don't know what they're doing in a more general sense; in which case you might consider moving to a different company.

Comment: Well, they just answered that they use http://www.modsecurity.org/ as their security module and that I should report to its documentation. 
So it can happen to anyone having a hosting company using this module I suppose.
I am not sure I spoke to technical person, but anyway, I think I got the answer now and will ask them to disable this specific feature.
Thanks to everybody !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't, your host is being stupid. There's nothing magical about the string `/id`.

Sometimes people do stupid things with the string `/id`, like assuming no one is going to guess what follows, so that `example.com/mysensitivedata/id/3/` shows my data because my user has `id` 3, and being the sneaky sort, I wonder what happens if I navigate to `example.com/mysensitivedata/id/4/`, and your site blindly lets me through to see someone else's stuff.

If that sort of attack breaks your site, no amount of mollycoddling by your host will help you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One reason a simple ID in the URL could be a security concern is that a user could see their ID and then type another one in, such as if its an integer they may select the next integer up, and potentially see another users info if it is not protected.

Comment: You are both answering the same, so I think I can reasonably ask them to disable this specific feature...
Thank you  very much !!