# Zend_OpenId_Consumer::login() fails

Tags: zend-framework, openid

I'm trying to implement OpenID. I've cut my code right back to try and get OpenID to work (as a consumer) but the login() methof just keeps failing! Here's the code:

```
require 'Zend/Http/Client.php';
require 'Zend/OpenId/Consumer.php';

$client = new Zend_Http_Client(null, array(
    'adapter'    => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl',
));

$consumer = new Zend_OpenId_Consumer();
$consumer->setHttpClient($client);

$url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';

$res = $consumer->login($url, 
                        'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 
                        '*');

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($res);
echo '</pre>';

return;
```

$res, is always FALSE.

I'm using PHP 5.2.10, i've got allow_url_fopen ON, cURL enabled and openssl enabled. I've tried the code on my local dev machine and my production environment and nether work!

Can anyone point me in the right direction, i'm really stumped with this one!

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hack and don't use the OpenID Enabled library (if you want to stick with ZF).

Akeem's developed a great solution here: http://ak33m.com/?p=71&cpage=1

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: the discovery fails [here](http://framework.zend.com/code/browse/Zend_Framework/standard/tags/release-1.9.2/library/Zend/OpenId/Consumer.php?r=9398#l665), because `Zend_OpenId_Consumer` [doesn't understand OpenID 2.0 (7.3) XRI](http://framework.zend.com/code/browse/Zend_Framework/standard/tags/release-1.9.2/library/Zend/OpenId/Consumer.php?r=9398#l633) as provided by google yet. for a workaround, see [How do I implement Direct Identity based OpenID authentication with Zend OpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741345/how-do-i-implement-direct-identity-based-openid-authentication-with-zend-openid/844350#844350). UPDATE END

try printing `$consumer->getError()` instead of the `var_dump()`. i get a

```
Discovery failed: HTTP Request failed: Error in cURL request: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

this indicates a problem with the verification of google's ssl certificate. there are several solutions for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818063/why-doesnt-google-openid-provider-work-with-php-openid-on-my-server) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992682/janrains-php-openid-and-google-yahoo) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497240/406-not-acceptable-error-when-using-janrain-openid-library-with-google).

Comment: I don't get cURL errors like you. Weird. All i receive is "Discovery failed: " without a reason! I've read the links you've kindly posted and since tried this amend: 

$config = array(
    'adapter'   => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl',
    'curloptions' => array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false),
);
$client = new Zend_Http_Client(null, $config);


But it still doesnt work, and i still dont get a meaningful error message!

Comment: This SSL error may also happen in chrooted environment when not all certificates are copied to chroot. For example in Ubuntu you should mount[copy] the path **/usr/share/ca-certificates**. My colleague and I spent several hours trying to get it working.

Comment: @TomaszStruczyński Also do not forgot to copy /etc/ssl/certs - both DIRs are required